# When i click one button its open all buttons simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick

When I click on the post button it opens all buttons like media and user .i tried to define state function but when i click one button all buttons are open simultaneously.

[this problem i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pog5A.png)

My code are here

export default function ListItem() {

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);


const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
};


return (
    <div>
        <List
            sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}
            component="nav"
            aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
        >
            {/* dashbord */}
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <DashboardTwoToneIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="DashBoard" />
            </ListItemButton>

            {/* post */}
            <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <PostAddTwoToneIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Post" />
                {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            </ListItemButton>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <List component="div" disablePadding>
                    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} component="a" href="#">
                        <ListItemText primary="New post" component="a" />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} component="a" href="#">
                        <ListItemText primary="All posts" />
                    </ListItemButton>
                </List>
            </Collapse>

            {/* Media */}
            <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <SubscriptionsTwoToneIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Media" />
                {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            </ListItemButton>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <List component="div" disablePadding>
                    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} component="a" href="#">
                        <ListItemText primary="All Media" component="a" />
                    </ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} component="a" href="#">
                        <ListItemText primary="Add New Media" />
                    </ListItemButton>
                </List>
            </Collapse>
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using so we can help identify the problem, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: Hi Ben now you can see my code in question.

Comment: You are using a single boolean state for all of them. Is it just the two buttons or are there more? Are you mapping an array of data to these buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a single boolean state for all of them. I suggest storing the open status of each item/element you want to toggle in an object and check if the specific item/element is currently toggled open.

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState({});

const handleClick = (id) => () => {
  setOpen(open => ({
    ...open,
    [id]: !open[id],
  }));
};
```

...

```
<ListItemButton onClick={handleClick("post")}> // <-- pass id
  <ListItemIcon>
    <PostAddTwoToneIcon />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText primary="Post" />
  {open["post"] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />} // <-- check by id
</ListItemButton>
<Collapse
  in={open["post"]} // <-- check by id
  timeout="auto"
  unmountOnExit
>
  <List component="div" disablePadding>
    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} component="a" href="#">
      <ListItemText primary="New post" component="a" />
    </ListItemButton>
    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} component="a" href="#">
      <ListItemText primary="All posts" />
    </ListItemButton>
  </List>
</Collapse>
```

Apply same for other buttons and collapsables but using specific unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

You call function setOpen on a click on any object, however setOpen seems to change the state of a global variable that is used to determine whether the contents should be shown or not. Try to set a unique variable as open state for every button and only change this variable with a function in onClick